# Emberjs Handlebars #each helper slow when bound to computed properties

Tags: ember.js

I'm running into a performance issue when I render a list of items using the #each helper or a collection view bound to some computed properties of an Ember.ArrayController. Performance is fine with a small list of 10 - 20 items, but around 50 - 100 it starts to lag quite noticeably. Try checking off a few todos or clicking "Add Todo"

Example code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jonesy/ed3ZS/4/

I noticed that the childViews in the DOM get re-rendered with each change, which could very well be the intended behaviour at the moment, but I'd prefer to be able to just have a todo be removed from the DOM of unfinished todos list individually and appended to the bottom of the finished todos list, which would in theory be much less costly.

What I'm hoping to have answered is whether am I looking at a performance issue with Ember collection views, or is displaying a list populated from a computed property a bad idea, and if so, will I need to manually manage the todo model's location in the view layer as it changes from unfinished to finished and vice versa.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a side-effect of how `{{#each}}` (and `CollectionView`, which is what powers it) works.

Internally, `CollectionView` uses something called *array observers*. An array observer allows you to subscribe to mutations made to an array when they are done using `Ember.Array`'s mutation methods (`replace`, `pushObject`, `popObject`, etc.) The API for array observers [is described here](http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.Array.html#method=addArrayObserver).

What this means is that, if you push a new object into a collection view, it will insert render one new element in the DOM and leave the rest in place.

In the example you posted, however, the array is not being mutated--you're creating a brand new `Array` object every time a new item is added or removed. When the binding synchronizes, it *replaces* the old array with the new array. To `{{#each}}`, this is no different than removing all of the elements and then adding them back in.

The solution to the problem is to use a single array, instead of a computed property that returns a different array object each time it changes. You can see [the Contacts app for an example of how to do this](https://github.com/emberjs/examples/tree/master/contacts).

Obviously this is a very common pattern, and we'd like to add some kind of filtering that does the right thing by default to `Ember.ArrayController` down the road.

Comment: Is this still the case in Ember 1.0.0-RC.1 and do you have an updated example?

Comment: @Tom, the contacts app you linked is dead now.